# Why would Space Cube 1.0 have so many On-Orbit Upsets over South America?

Tags: low-earth-orbit, radiation, computing

I was reading about the [Advanced Hybrid On-Board Science Data Processor - SpaceCube 2.0 Space Cube 2.0](https://esto.nasa.gov/conferences/estf2011/presentations/Flatley_ESTF20111.pdf) and I saw maps of computer upsets in orbit recorded by Space Cube 1.0 on slides 8 and 9. What is going on near South America, why so many upsets there? What's the physics behind the phenomenon?

---

[image]

[image]

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/South_Atlantic_Anomaly

Comment: somewhat related in Astronomy SE: [Why wasn't CHEOPS data taken during passage through the South Atlantic Anomaly downlinked in this case, resulting in gaps in photometry?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/41054/7982)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The lower map appears to show the [South Atlantic Anomaly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/South_Atlantic_Anomaly) (SAA), an area where the inner Van Allen radiation belt comes closest to the surface of the Earth.

From the linked article:

> The effect is caused by the non-concentricity of the Earth and its
>   magnetic dipole. The SAA is the near-Earth region where the Earth's
>   magnetic field is weakest relative to an idealized Earth-centered
>   dipole field.

The article gives a good side view showing the asymmetry:

[image]

Orbiting objects that pass through the SAA are subject to increased radiation flux compared to other portions of their orbit.

Edit:
Here's a picture from my personal collection showing the instructor station of the Shuttle Mission Simulator (from long ago).  On the far wall you can see a framed copy of a paper groundtrack map, with the South Atlantic Anomaly marked on it in gray.  Wish I had a closeup! But you can see there is no North Atlantic Anomaly.

[image]

Comment: And the physics is? (Why does the VanAllen radiation belt dip lower there? Why does radiation reach there with so much more intensity?

Comment: Did you read the linked article?

Comment: "Go read Wikipedia" could be a valid comment, but not an answer. I felt a nice tidy answer including *why* a dip in the field "mysteriously attracts" the VanAllen belt would be important for future readers, thus I included "*What's the physics behind the phenomenon?*" in the original question.

Comment: Well, the answer to this question is completely obvious/trivial to anyone who's ever heard of the SAA.  But, I recognize that it is difficult to google an answer in this case, if you don't know the key phrase.  When the Wikipedia article is completely satisfactory, and the problem is just finding it, it seems ridiculous to cut and past the whole article.  I assume this is why @pericynthion just commented with a link to the article, which seems completely valid to me.

Comment: So a good answer would be helpful to people who have NOT heard of the SAA. It would just mention [Cyclotron radius](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gyroradius) and the fact that particles hit a certain field and turn around (at the ends of the belts).

Comment: Go for it! I look fwd to reading and upvoting it!

Comment: Have a look at https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f6/World_Magnetic_Field_2015.pdf The minimum of magnetic field intensity is located at the south atlantic region.

Comment: Is it valid to interpret the figure geometrically here? That is to say that the SAA occurs where it does because the red lobes are equidistant from the purple axis and thus the red lobes are closer to the Earth on the right hand side of this 2D image. Just to test this understanding, is there a corresponding nearly-as-high radiation flux zone at the North end of the same lobe - i.e. coinciding with the the Atlantic coast of the US and the intermediate counts of on-orbit upsets in the original question?

Comment: I think the tilt of the purple axis means that the Northern lobe doesn't come as close to the surface of the Earth.  I've never heard of a North Atlantic Anomaly (the SAA was marked on all our NASA tracking maps, back when they were paper).  I will edit the question to add this.

Comment: I hope to post a supplemental answer with some gory details about fields, but this one is looking great and should be primary. Thanks!!

Comment: @Puffin one issue is that Earth's real field could be said to be a *lumpy dipole*. If you mathematically express the real, lumpy field as a tilted and *off-center* dipole, it will do it's best to try to fit the SAA. But that's just a simple model. The real SAA is more narrowly localized than the off-center dipole could show, and it's better to use a much larger expansion in spherical harmonics (also a model) traditionally centered on the Earth's center. Earth's near-surface magnetic field is produced by a complicated real-world jumble of currents and fields deep inside the planet.

Comment: @Puffin We get exposed to pictures like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sl7N1.gif from a very early age, whereas we should be thinking more like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nk2rn.gif To answer your comment directly - once the simple off-center dipole model is used, one of the four lobe-ends can approach closer to the Earth than the other three in this 2D (mis)representation. Actually that's precisely why this (fudged) explanation is invoked. In that 2D pic, *the sums* of lobe-to-surface distances of *opposite pairs* are still approximately equal.

Comment: @OrganicMarble better [late than never](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/34696/12102)

Comment: @OrganicMarble somewhat related in Astronomy SE: [Why wasn't CHEOPS data taken during passage through the South Atlantic Anomaly downlinked in this case, resulting in gaps in photometry?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/41054/7982)

Comment: @uhoh thanks! By one of those odd coincidences there was an interesting question in Skeptics recently that touched on the SAA https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/a/50229

Comment: @OrganicMarble I don't have the temperament to handle Skeptics, but there is a thing over India https://space.stackexchange.com/a/25466/12102 It turns out to be a low field as well

Comment: @uhoh yeah. I only look at it occasionally.

Comment: @OrganicMarble I left a comment there, thanks for the heads-up!

Answer (score 4):

I'm a little late but I've been meaning to add this as a supplement to @OrganicMarble's [answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/20422/12102).

Just like the Earth's gravity field, it's magnetic field is lumpy. But the lumpiness shows up differently.

**For Earth's gravity field** we start with the monopole field or central attraction. The Earth doesn't have a dipole gravity field because that's zeroed out by definition of where the center is. The first correction is the axisymmetric quadrupole field caused by Earth's oblateness caused by Earths' rotation and expresses as J2.

This is well aligned to Earth's equator because it's produced by rotation.

**For Earth's magnetic field** there is of course no monopole field and the first term is the dipole field. But since there is so much intellectual inertia invested in the idea that the Earth's field is a dipole, instead of talking about higher order terms it's easier to capture the deviation or "main lumpiness" by saying that the dipole is not in the center of the Earth and it's tilted by about 11.5 degrees.

[image]  [image]

Dipole thinking (left, [Source](http://spiff.rit.edu/classes/phys313/lectures/aur/aur.html)) versus what it is (right, [Source](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Geodynamo_Between_Reversals.gif))

### [Did I mention](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/20421/why-would-space-cube-1-0-have-so-many-on-orbit-upsets-over-south-america#comment108440_34696) cyclotron radius?

Particles are trapped in the van Allen radiation belts because their low energy keeps them there. As the cycle in helical orbits around the field lines, they reach a north and south extreme where their cyclotron radius based on their energy prevents them from traveling further; all velocity needs to be perpendicular to the field lines. At this point they "mirror" or reflect back and go the other way to put things loosely.

When the field is weak, that mirror or reflection point moves closer to the Earth's surface, as low as about 200 km some times, and that sends the ISS at its nominal 400 km orbit straight through the tail of the inner van Allen belt when it passes through the South Atlantic Anomaly.

@OrganicMarble's [answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/20422/12102) includes the image below, where you see the "toe" of the inner Van Allen radiation belt on the right side getting close to the Earth.

---

If you just plot a dipole field tilted and offset by 500 kilometers, you can reproduce the "weak spot" in Earths' field qualitatively. The real anomaly seems to have a different shape and sharper transition, and that's because the dipole model is simply not a good approximation to begin with.  It is what it is.

[image]

**below:** plot of an estimate of the field strength of the Earth in LEO based on 11.5 degree inclination and a 500 km offset of Earth's dipole, for latitudes between 50N and 50S; [Python](https://pastebin.com/F6jJYQrK).

[image]

**below:** plot of [South Atlantic Anomaly](https://heasarc.gsfc.nasa.gov/docs/rosat/gallery/display/saa.html) *an increase in radiation* which is correlated with areas of lowest magnetic field strength.

The two plots should not be compared directly as they show very different things.

[image]

[Source](https://heasarc.gsfc.nasa.gov/docs/rosat/gallery/display/saa.html) from [here](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/101/12102)

Comment: @Chris yikes!! Okay I'll get right on it. I'd forgotten about all of that.

Comment: @Chris how does that look?