# Biggest orbital inclination change done in Earth's orbit

Tags: low-earth-orbit, geostationary, earth, record, inclination-change

Generally orbital inclination change is said to be (fuel) expensive. What is the biggest orbital inclination change (in degrees) done in Earth's orbit for an orbiting object? Can this be broken down by orbits (LEO, geostationary etc.) and by mission (commercial satellite, military/governmental, human spaceflight etc.)?

Comment: potential candidates might be found in [What inclination change could the 5th stage Orion 38 motor provide ORS-5 (SensorSat)?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/22809/12102) and [Has anything ever executed an orbit change such as between ISS and Hubble?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/16940/12102) and [Spacecraft Maneuvers as Intellectual Property? Wow!](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/15224/12102) and [Would lunar flyby be less costly in delta-v than direct change from ISS's to Hubble's orbit?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/16945/12102) Big changes can sometimes be done with the Moon

Answer (score 6):

For low-earth orbit satellites, the [IXPE satellite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IXPE) was launched from Canaveral to a 28.5 degree orbit. The 2nd stage of the falcon rocket then changed its inclination to a 0.2 degree, equatorial, orbit.

This odd maneuver was done to prevent the sensitive x-ray payload of the satellite from being exposed to the [South Atlantic anomaly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/South_Atlantic_Anomaly).

For more on that see:

- [What is the South Atlantic Anomaly, and what can I do to protect satellites from it?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/10/12102)
- [Why wasn't CHEOPS data taken during passage through the South Atlantic Anomaly downlinked in this case, resulting in gaps in photometry?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/41054/7982)
- [Why would Space Cube 1.0 have so many On-Orbit Upsets over South America?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/20421/12102)